# Oracle mergin huge amount data from multiple sources into one table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

hi I am trying to solve problem with synchronization. I have three similar tables contains ID column + 10 more columns in three stand alone database connected by DB-link. Each table have 1.288 billion rows

What i need, is in one of db create evidence table

Expected result:

| ID | availaible_in_db1 | availaible_in_db2 | availaible_in_db3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 'Y' | 'N' | 'Y' |
| 234 | 'N' | 'N' | 'N' |
| 345 | 'Y' | 'Y' | 'Y' |

What came to my mind

- Step one - create localy Index Organised Table (IOT) for each database - just with IDs
- Step two - populate/ create table with Global_STATUS with all IDs and regionaly Y/N

In step one, I use CTAS (Create table as select) using parralel hint. And table was create about 17 mins. - its pretty good

In step two I try use Merge statement.... but my db run out of UNDO. Cursor has been running for many hours and still no result... The operation must be quick, ideally to 2-3 hours and reliable at the same time.

And I am running out of ideas how to solve it.
Will be happy for any idea or solution!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how long does it take you to copy remote IOT to another instance?

Comment: Via Db-link it takes more then 32hours, So I created locally IOT, and export/import into db1. It takes about 2-3hours.

Answer (score 0):

An IOT is probably not a good choice. You will be doing full table scans so the index structure would not benefit you, and it eliminates the ability to apply compression. Plus any other indexes would be wider because they have to hold the PK value in their leaf blocks.

As all you need to know is that the value is present, the ID column is the only column you need to pull across the links. In modern versions of Oracle it can pull the IDs serially (as all db link traffic is) and then transition to parallel for the join. In older versions or if you have trouble with that, you could write the IDs to a temp table as a first step so the join can be a non-distributed query.

Lastly, because you don't have a master with all the IDs, you'll need to a full join  (or something that amounts to it) and that requires moving data across the wire twice. So, materializing locally is a good idea no matter what.  Try something like this:

```
WITH db1 AS (SELECT /*+ materialize */ id
               FROM table@db1),
     db2 AS (SELECT /*+ materialize */ id
               FROM table@db2),
     db3 AS (SELECT /*+ materialize */ id
               FROM table@db3),
     full AS (SELECT id
                FROM db1
              UNION
              SELECT id
                FROM db2
              UNION
              SELECT id
                FROM db3)
SELECT /*+ parallel(8) */
       full.id,
       DECODE(db1.id,NULL,'N','Y') db1,
       DECODE(db2.id,NULL,'N','Y') db2,
       DECODE(db3.id,NULL,'N','Y') db3
  FROM full
       LEFT OUTER JOIN db1 ON db1.id = full.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN db2 ON db2.id = full.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN db3 ON db3.id = full.id
```